# Docker: Unable to run dotnet restore on asp.net core 2.1

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

While running docker-compose build, on dotnet restore I am getting the following error.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.802\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\src\<ProjectName>\ProjectName.csproj]
```

Find the docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  projectname.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}projectname
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: projectname\Dockerfile
```

Find the DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 52000:80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["<ProjectName>.API/<ProjectName>.API.csproj", "<ProjectName>.API/"]
COPY ["<ProjectName>.Core/<ProjectName>.Core.csproj", "<ProjectName>.Core/"]
COPY ["<ProjectName>.NetCore/<ProjectName>.NetCore.csproj", "<ProjectName>.NetCore/"]
COPY ["<ProjectName>.Repository/<ProjectName>.Repository.csproj", "<ProjectName>.Repository/"]
COPY ["<ProjectName>.Service/<ProjectName>.Service.csproj", "<ProjectName>.Service/"]
RUN dotnet restore "<ProjectName>.API/<ProjectName>.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/<ProjectName>.API"
RUN dotnet build "<ProjectName>.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "<ProjectName>.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<ProjectName>.API.dll"]
```

Where am I doing mistake? Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: In your Dockerfile, try putting `WORKDIR "/src/<ProjectName>.API"` before  `RUN dotnet restore ...` I have a hunch (not positive) that you have to be in the directory for `dotnet restore` to work. Here's an example of a project that works that I wrote that is doing something very similar, if it's helpful: https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/139ed1957950fc0549e240cafda423892c194a6f/src/FilterLists.Api/Dockerfile#L20